# How to configure a single-threaded ForkJoinPool?

Tags: java, multithreading, fork-join, forkjoinpool

**Is it possible to configure `ForkJoinPool` to use 1 execution thread?**

I am executing code that invokes `Random` inside a `ForkJoinPool`. Every time it runs, I end up with different runtime behavior, making it difficult to investigate regressions.

I would like the codebase to offer "debug" and "release" modes. "debug" mode would configure `Random` with a fixed seed, and `ForkJoinPool` with a single execution thread. "release" mode would use system-provided `Random` seeds and use the default number of `ForkJoinPool` threads.

I tried configuring `ForkJoinPool` with a parallelism of 1, but it uses 2 threads (`main` and a second worker thread). Any ideas?

Comment: There is a much better performing random for release mode https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/threadlocalrandom.html

Comment: @zapl I already use `ThreadLocalRandom` for release mode. This question isn't about improving performance. It is about improving ease-of-debugging by configuring `ForkJoinPool` to use a single thread.

Comment: Have you tried setting parallelism to 0?

Comment: @pvg Yes. The Javadoc states that this is illegal and the code throws an exception if you try.

Comment: @Gili it does? What JDK are you using? The docs/impl notes I'm looking at say things like "It is possible to disable or limit the use of threads in the common pool by setting the parallelism property to zero, and/or using a factory that may return null" for JDK 8.

Comment: @pvg I am running JDK 1.8.0_66. According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#ForkJoinPool-int- `parallelism` may not be zero. I see the sentence you are referring to, but (1) I want to configure the number of threads used by a new `ForkJoinPool` instance, not the common instance. (2) If you dig into the JDK source-code you will discover that setting the aforementioned property to zero will result in the aforementioned exception. In short, this won't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797568/what-determines-the-number-of-threads-a-java-forkjoinpool-creates

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, it turns out I was wrong.

When you configure a `ForkJoinPool` with `parallelism` set to 1, only one thread executes the tasks. The `main` thread is blocked on `ForkJoin.get()`. It doesn't actually execute any tasks.

That said, it turns out that it is really tricky providing deterministic behavior. Here are some of the problems I had to correct:

- `ForkJoinPool` was executing tasks using different worker threads (with different names) if the worker thread became idle long enough. For example, if the main thread got suspended on a debugging breakpoint, the worker thread would become idle and shut down. When I would resume execution, `ForkJoinThread` would spin up a new worker thread with a different name. To solve this, I had to provide a custom `ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory` implementation that ensures only one thread runs at a time, and that its name is hard-coded. I also had ensure that my code was returning the same `Random` instance even if a worker thread shut down and came back again.
- Collections with non-deterministic iteration order such as `HashMap` or `HashSet` led to elements grabbing random numbers in a different order on every run. I corrected this by using `LinkedHashMap` and `LinkedHashSet`.
- Objects with non-deterministic hashCode() implementations, such as `Enum.hashCode()`. I forget what problems this caused but I corrected it by calculating the hashCode() myself instead of relying on the built-in method.

Here is a sample implementation of ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory:

```
class MyForkJoinWorkerThread extends ForkJoinWorkerThread
{
    MyForkJoinWorkerThread(ForkJoinPool pool)
    {
        super(pool);
        // Change thread name after ForkJoinPool.registerWorker() does the same
        setName("DETERMINISTIC_WORKER");
    }
}

ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory factory = new ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory()
{
    private WeakReference<Thread> currentWorker = new WeakReference<>(null);

    @Override
    public synchronized ForkJoinWorkerThread newThread(ForkJoinPool pool)
    {
        // If the pool already has a live thread, wait for it to shut down.
        Thread thread = currentWorker.get();
        if (thread != null && thread.isAlive())
        {
            try
            {
                thread.join();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                log.error("", e);
            }
        }
        ForkJoinWorkerThread result = new MyForkJoinWorkerThread(pool);
        currentWorker = new WeakReference<>(result);
        return result;
    }
};
```

Comment: Good. It would be helpful for others if you post some important blocks of code related to ThreadFactory.

Answer (score 1):

Main thread is always the first thread your application will create. So when you create a `ForkJoinPool` with `parallelism` of `1`, you are creating another thread. Effectively there will be two threads in the application now ( because you created a `pool` of threads ).

If you need only one thread that is Main, you can execute your code in sequence ( and not in parallel at all ).

Comment: I already know this. To clarify, I need to be able to alter the number of threads used by `ForkJoinPool` without altering the rest of my code. Your suggestion to execute code in sequence (dumping the use of `ForkJoinPool`) implies a design-level change every time I wish to switch between "debug" and "release" modes.

Comment: Could you update your question with a small code that demonstrates your issue?