# Multi threading database reading

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, jdbc

In our Java application I have requirement to read the around 80 million records from oracle database. I am trying to redesign the multithreading program for this. Currently we are using Java 5 thread pooling with 10 threads reading the data base in parallel based on a primary key pattern. Each thread will read  different pattern like 001* and 002*.

How can I improve the performance of this program? I am thinking of design pattern, having lead thread to read the database and delegate the processing to child threads. In our existing design, different threads access the table by having 10  jdbc connections. With the new approach I will have only one thread reading the table.

We have different select statement for each thread like select `count(*) from "+table+ " where id like '"+format + "%'"`.

Ok sounds reading rowid pattern good, but is it good to read by rowid or rownum ?

Can any body please pros and cons of new approach and is there other way we can implement it.

Comment: Without knowing the sources of your bottleneck, redesigning it is just as likely to make the problem worse, as better.  I suggest you invest more time determining why the download of data takes so long, and design your software to work around this.

Comment: You probably won't get big performance boost from threading, as DB operations might turn out to be IO bound. I'd start with removing threading altogether.

Comment: Indeed - if you have the database stored on a single physical hard drive, multithreaded reading may just make the problem worse as it may lead to more disk seeks.

Comment: Don't split by a "pattern" unless you're fairly sure that it's evenly distributed. It's better to split by blocks on rowid so that you pick out information that's close together on the disk and with large volumes is normally very evenly split. Are you chunking it or just running 10 threads with a single select each?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have modified question with more details.

Comment: Java is not an acronym

Comment: Why would you ever want to ship 80M rows from the database to another layer? Likely there is a cheap alternative which does the processing inside the database (using a simple parallel select) and ship only the results to your Java application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Network

First of all, since using *rowid* and *rownum* is vendor-lock anyway, you should consider using database stored routines. It could significantly reduce overhead of transmitting data from database to the application server (especially if they are on different machines and connected through network).

Considering that you have 80 million records to transmit, that could be the best performance boost for you, though it depends on kind of work your threads do.

Obviously increasing bandwidth would also help to solve networking issues.

### Disk performance

Before making changes in code check the hard drive load while tasks running, perhaps it just can't handle that much I/O (10 threads reading simultaneously).

Migrating to SSD/RAID or clustering database might solve the issue. While changing the way you access database won't in that case.

Multithreading could solve CPU problems, but databases mostly depend on disk system.

### Rownum

There are a couple of problems you might face if you will be implementing it using rowid and rownum.

1) *rownum* is generated on the fly for each query's results. So if query doesn't have explicit 
sorting and it is possible that some record have different rownum every time you run query.

For example you run it first time and get results like this:

```
some_column | rownum
____________|________
     A      |    1
     B      |    2
     C      |    3
```

then you run it second time, since you don't have explicit sorting, dbms (for some reason known to itself) decides to return results like this:

```
some_column | rownum
____________|________
     C      |    1
     A      |    2
     B      |    3
```

2) point 1 also implies that if you will be filtering results on *rownum* it will generate temporary table with **ALL** results and then filter it

**So *rownum* is not a good choice for splitting results.** While *rowid* seemed better, it has some issues too.

### Rowid

If you look at the [ROWID description](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) you may notice that "rowid value uniquely identifies a row in the **database**".

Because of that and the fact that when you delete a row you have a "hole" in rowid sequence, rowids may be distributed not equally among table records.

So for example if you have three threads and each fetching 1'000'000 rowids, it is possible that one will get 1'000'000 records and other two 1 record each. So one will be overwhelmed, while two other *starving*.

**It might be not a big deal in your case, though it very well might be the problem you are facing currently with primary key pattern.**

Or if you first fetch all rowids in dispatcher and then divide them equally (like peter.petrov suggested) that could do the thing, though fetching 80 million ids still sounds like a lot, I think it would be better to do the splitting with one sql-query that returns borders of chunks.

Or you might solve that problem by giving low amount of rowids per task and using Fork-Join framework introduced in Java 7, however it [should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677506/forkjoinpool-seems-to-waste-a-thread) [used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797568/what-determines-the-number-of-threads-a-java-forkjoinpool-creates) [carefully](http://coopsoft.com/ar/CalamityArticle.html).

Also obvious point: both rownum and rowid are not portable across databases.

So it is much better to have your own "sharding" column but then you will have to make sure yourself that it splits records in more or less equal chunks.

---

Also keep in mind that if you are going to do it in several threads it is important to check what **locking mode database uses**, perhaps it just locks the table for every access, then multithreading is pointless.

As others suggested, you'd better first find what is the main reason of low performance (network, disk, database locking, thread starvation or maybe you just have suboptimal queries - check the query plans).

Comment: Thanks for detailed information, I am working on this will come back once I found something some magical thing which makes performance improvements.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a dispatching thread which reads the PKs (the IDs) of N rows.
   Here you can do some sort of caching - read N=1000 rows, give them to Worker1,
   read next N=1000 rows, give them to Worker2, etc. This way, you don't need to 
   keep more than N=1000 IDs (PKs) in-memory in the dispatcher thread. Once you
   pass the work (the work is these N=1000 IDs) to the Worker thread, 
   you dispose them in the dispatcher thread (no need to keep them).
2. Each worker thread takes its N (e.g. 1000) PKs/IDs and using them 
   gets the rows from the DBs. Make sure here that you use rowlock (T-SQL) 
   or its equivalent if you're not using SQL Server. This way, the threads 
   will not get into each other's way. So worker reads N rows from the DB
   and processes them. Once complete it may signal the dispatcher
   (something like "I am done" event).

This is the initial idea that comes to my mind. I guess it 
could be refined further if you think some more on it.

Comment: Thanks, can I distribute rows  based oracle rowid or rownum , which is the better option ?

Comment: Well, I am not really familiar with Oracle, sorry. Haven't played with it for a long time now.

Comment: This idea cannot scale out. Though scaling up can help.. but resource restrictions comes into picture..

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, multithreading might not help and may even make matters worse.

Standard alternatives for any query are:

1. See what the query plan is and see if rejigging the SQL can improve
   the query plan.
2. Do more processing on the database side - but since you are doing a `SELECT COUNT...` there is nothing more you can do here!
3. See if you can rework the query to do [incremental computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_computing) based on new or updated rows since the last run, instead of querying over all old the data every time.

None of these are guaranteed to succeed. It would depend on what you are trying to do.